# PHP session variable not accessible on another page

Tags: php, session

After trawling through other posts, I could not find the answer.
The problem is that when i create a custom session name, I am not able to access session variables on any other pages. How can I get this working with custom session variable?

## Scenario A

*Login page*

after successful login, the following is called

```
function initiatenewsession($app, $userid){
    $session_name = getuniquesessionid($app,$userid);   // Set a custom session name
    session_name($session_name);
    session_start();
    session_regenerate_id(true);
    $_SESSION["loggeduserid"] = $user_id;
    echo("1a)SESSION NAME[".session_name()."]");
    echo("1b)logged user[".$_SESSION["loggeduserid"]."]");
}
```

Echo result

- 1a) SESSION NAME[myappsessionid6520150528184534]
- 1b) logged user[65]

*Registration page* (User clicks a link after logging in)

```
session_start();
echo("2a)SESSION NAME[".session_name()."]");
echo("2b)logged user[".$_SESSION["loggeduserid"]."]");
```

- 2a)SESSION NAME[PHPSESSID]
- 2b)logged user[]

## Scenario B

*Login page*

after successful login, the following is called

```
function initiatenewsession($app, $userid){
    session_start();
    session_regenerate_id(true);
    $_SESSION["loggeduserid"] = $user_id;
    echo("1a)SESSION NAME[".session_name()."]");
    echo("1b)logged user[".$_SESSION["loggeduserid"]."]");
}
```

Echo result

- 1a) SESSION NAME[PHPSESSID]
- 1b) logged user[65]

*Registration page* (User clicks a link after logging in)

```
session_start();
echo("2a)SESSION NAME[".session_name()."]");
echo("2b)logged user[".$_SESSION["loggeduserid"]."]");
```

- 2a)SESSION NAME[PHPSESSID]
- 2b)logged user[65]

Comment: your session name is changing, obviously. you have to tell php what session name to use EVERYWHERE you're using the session, otherwise it'll use its default one. that means you've got TWO sessions floating around: phpsessid and myappetc...

Comment: To simplify the point: you need to set the session name on all the pages.

Comment: include a config file like config.php at the top of every page and inside config.php, put the name of your session variable (and other commonly used variables used by your app)

Comment: You seem to confuse the session ID with the session name; the session ID is already unique and by setting the session name to `getuniquesessionid($app,$userid)` - which I assume is something random and unique - you will never be able to restart the same session. Unless you store it somewhere of course, like in a database, but that would just be generating additional overhead to start the session.

Comment: To even further simplify this: you need to set **the same** session name for **all** page loads (not just the login) for the same user if you want the session to be maintained.

Comment: Thanks. Its much clear now. Is there any showstoppers that I would have to face if i move forward not maintaining a session and use what PHP sets by default?  I'm new to PHP and thought of creating a custom session name just in case I would require more control. If I may ask here, why would one have to use a custom session name in PHP projects?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per my comment, when you do `session_start()`, php will check if you set a session name via `session_name()`, otherwise it'll use its default.

Session startup is basically like this, in php-ish pseudocode:

```
if (custom_session_name_was_set()) {
   $session_name = get_custom_session_name();
} else {
   $session_name = ini_get('session.name');
}

if (isset($_COOKIE[$session_name])) {
   $id = $_COOKIE[$session_name];
} else {
   $id = generate_new_random_id();
   setcookie($session_name, $id);
}

$session_data = file_get_contents('/path/to/session/files/' . $id);
$_SESSION = unserialize($session_data);
```

For your first bit of code, you set a custom name, so that's the name that's used for the session cookie.

In your other code, you do **NOT** set a custom name, so php uses its default: PHPSESSID. Now you've got two sessions floating around, each with their own unique names, and their own different IDs, and their own separate data in $_SESSION.

If you're going to be using custom session names, you have do `session_name($customName)` EVERYWHERE you have `session_start()`.

Comment: [This has answered my query. Just posting the same comment as in I did above] Thanks. Its much clear now. Is there any showstoppers that I would have to face if i move forward not maintaining a session and use what PHP sets by default? I'm new to PHP and thought of creating a custom session name just in case I would require more control. If I may ask here, why would one have to use a custom session name in PHP projects?

Comment: the session name itself is mostly irrelevant, as long as it's consistent. it COULD be a showstopper if, for some reason, you need to maintain two parallel sessions. e.g. log into your system as a user, then needing to open a separate 'admin' level session to do some stuff. you might want two different session names at that point, but you could accomplish the same thing by just using a browser in private mode, which wouldn't share cookies with other windows.

Answer (score 0):

1. If using a custom session name you *must* call `session_name()`.
2. You *must* call `session_start()` before `headers_sent()`.
3. On servers with multiple PHP version support check `phpversion()` to ensure that the server did not decide to run the wrong version (and hence the wrong `session_save_path()`).